# Windows PowerShell cannot recognize sqlite3

Tags: powershell

I have installed SQLite3 on my computer in G:\SQLite3\sqlite3.exe

However, when I type "sqlite3" (no quotes) to PowerShell, it gives me the following error:

```
sqlite3 : The term 'sqlite3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, functio
n, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a pa
th was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sqlite3
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sqlite3:String) [], CommandNotF
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

My Environmental Path includes G:\SQLite3, so when I run sqlite3 in command prompt (cmd.exe), it runs just fine. I prefer PowerShell though, so I would be glad, if someone could point me in the right direction how to make it accept this command. If that matters, I use Windows 8.

Comment: If you type the absolute path `G:\SQLite3\sqlite3.exe` or  `& "G:\SQLite3\sqlite3.exe"` it run ?

Comment: Yes, it runs with absolute path. I don't want to type it everytime though ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely the directory `G:\SQLite3` is not in your `PATH` environment variable, so PowerShell doesn't know where to look for the executable. Either run the executable with its full path, or add the directory to the `$env:PATH`:

```psh
$env:PATH += ';G:\SQLite3'
& sqlite3.exe
```

Comment: Your answer worked well - after typing that command to PowerShell, everything is good. However, I'm not sure WHY it worked - I already had the 'G:\SQLite3' in my Path variable, as proved by the fact that cmd.exe didn't have that problem. Perhaps it is the upper case that matters? (Path vs. PATH)

Comment: No, capitalization shouldn't make a difference. PowerShell is case-insensitive there. Double-check the spelling. Did you perhaps have `C:\SQLite` instead of `G:\SQLite` in `$env:PATH`?

Comment: Nope. I hope that I am looking in the good place there - Computer Properties > Advanced > Environmental Variables > Path. But it seems that it has a different set of paths than the one printed in teh PowerShell after typing $env:PATH - in particular, the one checked in console has "G:\SQLite3" appended to the end, and the other one in the beginning, where I typed it myself... Is there any difference?

Comment: Also, it seems that the solution is only temporary - when I restarted the PowerShell, the sqlite3 command stopped working again. Typing the $env:PATH += ';G:\SQLite3' solves the issue again, but it is tedious to have to write it every time I turn on the PowerShell. Is there any better solution perhaps?

Comment: OK. I seem to have found the real problem. And I feel quite stupid. After restarting the whole computer, everything works as I initially wanted.